# Simple cross platform TCP IP API?

Tags: c++, c, api, tcp

I'm not looking to use something big like QT or wxWidgets' APIs. I just want simple sockets that will work on Android, iOS, Windows, Mac, Linux.

I'm making an event driven card game so TCP would be best.

Essentially, I just want to connect and authenticate clients. After that I just need to be able to send them messages. I was going to use reliable UDP but TCP seems more appropriate.

If anyone also has basic tutorials for something like a tcp chat application I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

I just want to be able to use, send(), recv, etc without worrying about WINSOCK or POSIX,

Comment: You could try [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) or [liblacewing](http://lacewing-project.org).

Comment: liblacewing seems perfect! thanks!

Comment: @James McLaughlin Does Lacewing work on iOS? Well, just the client and server classes. If not do you plan to add support for this? Thanks!

Comment: @Milo Theoretically it should work fine, but I've never tried to compile it for iOS. If not, it's certainly something that will be added in the near future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps try BOOST Asio

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Is that light weight enough?

Comment: boost::asio seems complicated. The example is using smart pointers and a few other things that seem unnessesary.

Comment: I just want something or a simple tutorial that allows me to connect send receive and disconnect.

Comment: Perhaps just go with POSIX then. POSIX code can compile on just about every operating system if you get the right dependencies in place.

Comment: Why would someone bother making an exception to use winsock on windows then?

Comment: Although they work fine, berkeley sockets can never really be scalable on Windows because only select(2) is available. There's nothing similar to epoll or kqueue, and to use I/O completion ports you have to use WSARecv instead of recv etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a really simple, lightweight wrapper around the BSD Sockets API. It does TCP/IP communication only, using a server and a client (a server can optionally accept multiple client connections).

You can find it here: (don't mind the Objective-C classes, use tcpconnect.h and tcpconnect.c only): http://github.com/H2CO3/TCPHelper

Comment: I also do not see functions to send and receive data.

Comment: In case your Windows version supports BSD sockets. (Since it's only standard C, it should be portable enough, although I don't know qhat kind of design errors Windows might have in the sense of lacking standard features). Ty it, if it's working, good, if it's not, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Because you write() and read() as my functions return a file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Perharps Boost.Asio (http://boost.org) or this one http://libunicomm.org based on Asio could be useful for you.